# Angular JS form validatior

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have problem with validating form, I have this validation example which show errors only when in first input is invalid value, when in first field is valid value there are no error shown.

[link](http://jsbin.com/wesawojike/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Instead of using signup_form.name.$dirty && signup_form.name.$invalid && signup_form.submitted
Use this :-
    <div class="error"
                 ng-show="signup_form.email.$dirty && signup_form.email.$invalid && signup_form.submitted">

    <div class="error"
               ng-show="signup_form.username.$dirty && signup_form.username.$invalid && signup_form.submitted">
```

update:- http://jsbin.com/fajoreguxu/1/

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `name` in all the checks...

```
<div class="error" ng-show="signup_form.name.$dirty &&
```

You need to change the actual reference, so `email` would be...

```
<div class="error" ng-show="signup_form.email.$dirty &&
```